# How to add an object to an ARRAY, if its not already there

Tags: java, arrays

Ive checked everywhere and cant find an answer similar to my question, in java. I'm using an array, not an array list.

Every time a new order is placed at my CoffeeShop, the CoffeeShop must be added to an array of stores the customer has visited, but it should only appear once, even if they visited say 'Starbucks' twice.

I have a main file, a CoffeeShop class, and a Customer class, these 3 files all work together in OOP.

I have a feeling that my issue stems from how I have sending my Customer class the CoffeeShop object from within the CoffeeShop Class (AKA if sending 'this' is appropriate), or from how i am adding the CoffeeShop to the array in the 'addStore()' method (AKA if the index 'i' is doing what i think its doing).

Here is my code that adds a CoffeeShop object to the customer list of shops, in the main it looks like this:

```
secondCup.newOrder(bruno, latte); //bruno is a Customer object, latte is a Drink object.
```

and in my CoffeeShop class the new order instance method looks like:

```
public void newOrder(Customer c, Drink d)
{
    /* 
    double t = markUp*d.calculateCost();
    DrinkOrder o = new DrinkOrder(c, d, t);
    orders[pendingOrders++] = o;

    currentProfit += t - d.calculateCost();

    tracker[trackerSize++] = c;
    totalOrders++;
    */ //above is irrelevant 

    c.addStore(this); //Here is where im adding the store that called the 'newOrder()' method
}
```

I thought that 'this' should be the specific coffeeshop that called '.newOrder()', but in the main when a different store calls newOrder(), lets say:

```
starBucks.newOrder(bruno, latte);
```

When I print the array of shops visited, I get 2 secondCups, not both a second cup and a star bucks (i think this is either because of how im sending my CoffeeShop to addStore() or how im appending the store to the array of stores visited).

Here is my method that should check if the store already exists within the array, and if not, should add it to the array:

```
    public void addStore(CoffeeShop shop)
{
    size++;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (visited[i] == null) //if the first position is null (which it will be, add their first shop visited
        {
            visited[i] = shop;
            break;
        }

        else if (visited[i].equals(shop)) //if if the index of the array equals the shop passed, then break the loop AKA dont add it to the array
        {
            break;
        }

        else //if none of the positions equal the shop, add it to the array
        {
            visited[i] = shop;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using a do while, as shown below, but I got the exact same output as my attempt above:

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    do
    {
        visited[i] = shop; //complete atleast one action, because the customer hasnt visited anystore yet so the first store should always be added
    }
    while (!visited[i].equals(shop)); //add to the array as long as they're not equal
```

here is my output:

```
Total coffee orders: 6

Swift, Taylor has visited:
Starbucks
Starbucks
Starbucks

Mars, Bruno has visited:
Second Cup
Second Cup

Ada, Lovelace has visited:
Second Cup
```

this is what it should be (taylor visited starbucks twice, but it should only be added once):

```
Total coffee orders: 6

Swift, Taylor has visited:
Starbucks
Second Cup

Mars, Bruno has visited:
Starbucks
Second Cup

Ada, Lovelace has visited:
Second Cup
```

just in case here is my print method:

```
public void displayStoresVisited()
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        System.out.println(visited[i].getName());
}
```

getName() just returns the name of the CoffeeShop at index 'i' of my array of CoffeeShop(s) visited

Thank you all so much for the help! This is due tomorrow! <3

EDIT:
I changed the 'else' in the addStore() method thanks to a lovely answer below, and it gave me null pointer exception because it didn't know how to handle taylors 3rd store she visited (AKA starbucks twice) so I kindve cheekily just subtracted the for-loop iteration size by one if the shops are equal (as you can see below). I do not think this is the best way to do this, so if anyone has any tips from here on to handle this type of situation!

much appreciated!

```
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (visited[i] == null)
        {
            visited[i] = shop;
            break;
        }

        else if (visited[i].equals(shop))
        {
            size -= 1;
        }

        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Here was the error I got after I changed the code to what someone recommended if anyone is interested:

```
Total coffee orders: 6

Swift, Taylor has visited:
Starbucks
Second Cup
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Customer.displayStoresVisited(Customer.java:105)
        at TestPhase4.main(TestPhase4.java:82)
```

Comment: If you have an array you need either to go through all elements to detect if an equal element exists or sort it or create an index...     If you want Java to aid you, Id recommed to use a Collection instead: a Set for example. I did read and understand, that you use an Array. My point is, doing so might be the root cause of your troubles.

Comment: `elsr continue;` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i=0;
while((i<size) && (!visited[i].equals(shop))){
  ++i;
}
if(i>=visited.length){
   //increase the size of your array here.
}
if(i >= size){
   visited[i] = shop;  
   size++;
}


/* get rid of this:
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    if (visited[i] == null)
    {
        visited[i] = shop;
        break;
    }

    else if (visited[i].equals(shop))
    {
        size -= 1;
    }

    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
*/
```

Comment: you most probably don't need the array resize(skip it!) but I put it in just in  case. If you resize: increase in reasonable chunk sizes.

Comment: This worked and was great! I got rid of if (i>=visited.length) and it works great! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below from `addStore` is wrong because you are not adding to the array, you are replacing an existing shop with the new one (and then adding it later)

```
else //if none of the positions equal the shop, add it to the array
    {
        visited[i] = shop;
    }
```

replace it with

```
else {
    continue;
}
```

to check `visited` using next `i` or even better remove it completely since it the last else

Increase the `size` variable only when adding a new shop to the array

```
if (visited[i] == null) //if the first position is null (which it will be, add their first shop visited
    {
        visited[i] = shop;
        size++;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: This gave me this output: 

    Swift, Taylor has visited:
    Starbucks
    Second Cup
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Customer.displayStoresVisited(Customer.java:105)
        at TestPhase4.main(TestPhase4.java:82)

Comment: @Skonertm Well you increase your `size` variable every time you call `addStore` even if you don't add anything so you need to add some logic to handle that correctly (that is, not increase it for duplicates) or check for null in your display... method.

Comment: @Skonertm Added my view on how the `size` variable should be handled.

Comment: much appreciated !